# Initialize Multiple Delegate of Same Datatype

Tags: c#

I am working on windows form and using Thread safe concept to set the value of Main thread controls,here I have two delegates one is used with no argument and other is used to pass the argument but I found impossible to do this because it says

> Form already contain definition for StringArgReturningVoidDelegate

**Delegate declaration**

```
    delegate string StringArgReturningVoidDelegate();

    delegate void StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(string text);
```

Comment: AFAIR using `delegate` keyword is a (c# ?) compiler feature, when used it will in fact create a normal C# type: `class StringArgReturningVoidDelegate`, then this class is used as type by events and actual variables holding references to methods. This is why you can't have same name. Quickfix: use another name.

Comment: How can I rename a delegate when I am using Class as delegate name?

Comment: You don't have to use same as containing type name. In fact, they don't have to belong to class, you can [define delegate in the namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2343449/1997232) directly. [Naming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2346065/1997232) delegates is actually a subject. Currently there are `Action<>` and `Func<>` generics to define methods pointers and `EventHandler<>` for events. I am not even sure if there is a need to continue using `delegate` keyword.. In other words, don't define delegate types, use `Func<string>` for first and `Action<string>` for second.

Answer (score 3):

The delegates must me named uniquely within their enclosing type/namespace. I put it to you that the first one should possibly be `NoArgsReturningStringDelegate`, but: just using `Func<string>` and `Action<string>` rather than declaring your own delegate types would be easier...

Answer (score 1):

No.You cannot overload a delegate.

Some pointers as to why : 
[C# - How can I "overload" a delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747948/c-sharp-how-can-i-overload-a-delegate)

Some workarounds for this, you can find in this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41574140/4054186

Comment: Thanks to all for guide.